# hamburger menu moved after update

Tags: theming, navigation

We use we-mega-menu. After performing an update the mobile (hamburger) menu changed its alignment to the left as well as some other things I was able to fix the other things but I can't seem to figure out how to align the menu to the right within the container. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that styling is being driven by the flex display on `div.region-we-mega-menu`.
Creating a style that overrides `justify-content: flex-start;` to `justify-content: flex-end;` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem!